# Spring Data Solr - Exception in mapping a custom repository

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, facet, spring-data-solr

I am trying to use faceted search with a custom repository as follows:

Repository:

```
public interface POISearchRepository extends CustomSolrRepository, SolrCrudRepository<POISearch, String>
```

Custom interface:

```
public interface CustomSolrRepository { 

     FacetPage<POISearch> facetSearch(String location, String categories, String duration, Pageable page) throws Exception; 
}
```

Custom impl:

```
@Repository
public class POISearchImpl implements CustomSolrRepository {

@Resource
private SolrTemplate solrTemplate;

@Override
public FacetPage<POISearch> facetSearch(String location, String categories, String duration, Pageable page) throws Exception {

......
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property facet found for type com.example.domain.POISearch at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:75)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:271)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:72)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:180)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:260)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:240)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.PartTreeSolrQuery.(PartTreeSolrQuery.java:36)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(SolrRepositoryFactory.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:279)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
>   ... 57 more

It seems like the repository tries to resolve the custom method and that causes the exception (changing the method names shows that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the naming for my repository intrefaces. Fixes:

Repository : POISearchRepository
Custom interface: POISearchRepositoryCustom
Customer implementation: POISearchRepositoryImpl

My initial naming was not according to Spring Data spec